# Usage of @since and @version in private method documentation

Tags: java, javadoc, code-documentation

I'm reading up about when it is necessary to provide `@since` and `@version` in the documentation of Java classes, however when is it appropriate to provide them? Was their original purpose for all visibility types or only `public` and/or `protected`?

I understand that the `version` is specific to the iteration of the function or member, and the `since` is relative to what version it was introduced, but is it the correct practice to add it to every member and function?

Examples:

```
/**
 * @version 1.2
 * @since 1.0
 */
public void myPublicMethod() {
    // this would be acceptable
}

/**
 * @version 2.1
 * @since 1.5
 */
private void myPrivateMethod() {
    // but would this?
}
```

Comment: Those attributes are used to help others understand the public API, there's no *need* to put them on anything private. That said, there's nothing preventing you from doing so if you or the rest of your team find it useful.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm assuming this counts for all protected fields aswell then. Does this mean the question is necessarily "primarily opinion based"?

Comment: Basically you're asking if it is good practice to use the tools available to you to document code. It may be less relevant for a generated javadoc you present to external parties, but that is not the only purpose of javadocs both generated an in-code. Its also for you.